# Can't run debugging in Visual Studio Code on Chrome OS

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-os

How do I run a .html file in VS Code on Chrome OS? It sais I need to add the absolute path to browser in a Json file.

[Trying to open a .html file in VS Code on Chrome OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd9YO.png)

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Chrome OS, I was able to run it through Firefox and Chromium installed as Linux Apps on Linux Beta. But not in the default Chrome Browser on Chrome OS.

Comment: Would extensions like [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) help? Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

U need to install a separate version of Chrome on VS Code then it will work. I just had the same problem and found the solution somewhere hidden on Reddit, but it worked :-)

> sudo apt install chromium

Then you can add this to your .vscode/launch.json

> ```
>   "configurations": [
>     {
>       "type": "chrome",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
>       "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/chromium",
>       "url": "http://localhost:3000",
>       "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
>       "smartStep": true
>     }
>   ]
> ```

Comment: Yep - this looks like the solution, except that you do not need to specify the executable path once this is installed.  Note that your default browser in crostini (xdg-open and x-www-browser) will change to the chromium install.   This makes sense since the Google Chrome installation probably cannot be re-launched with a debug port on a Chromebook. The VS Code documentation does not lend much help here (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md).  Removing chromium does revert the browser redirect.